# Pandas: Best way to filter bottom 10% and top 25% of data within a groupby using quantile

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a time series in pandas with prices and times. I would like to group the dates by 1 month time intervals, calculate the 10-75% quantile of prices for each month and then filter the original dataframe using these values (so that only the prices that fall between 10% and 75% are left).

The dataframe looks something like this:

```
df =pd.DataFrame({'date':['01-01-16','02-05-16','01-06-16','01-03-16','01-04-16'],'price':[10,3,4,3,4]})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
df.index = df.date

             date      price
    date 
2016-01-01  2016-01-01  10
2016-01-06  2016-01-06  3
2016-01-03  2016-01-03  11
2016-01-04  2016-01-04  9
2016-02-05  2016-02-05  4
2016-02-12  2016-02-12  3
2016-02-15  2016-02-15  6
```

And the quantile in each month looks something like this:

```
dg = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('1M')).quantile([0.1,0.75])


                    price
date        
2016-01-31   0.10   4.80
             0.75   10.25
2016-02-29   0.10   3.20
             0.75   5.00
```

After filtering, I would like my final dataframe to look like:

```
             date      price
    date 
2016-01-01  2016-01-01  10
2016-01-04  2016-01-04  9
2016-02-05  2016-02-05  4
```

I am guessing there is probably an easier way to do this than what I am currently thinking - any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, define a function to check whether a Series is between the specified quantiles:

```
def in_qrange(ser, q):
    return ser.between(*ser.quantile(q=q))
```

This returns a boolean array. If you pass this to resample.transform, you will have:

```
df.resample('1M')['price'].transform(in_qrange, q=[0.1, 0.75])
Out: 
date
2016-01-01     True
2016-01-03    False
2016-01-04     True
2016-01-06    False
2016-02-05     True
2016-02-12    False
2016-02-15    False
Name: price, dtype: bool
```

You can use this to filter the original DataFrame:

```
df.loc[df.resample('1M')['price'].transform(in_qrange, q=[0.1, 0.75])]
Out: 
                  date  price
date                         
2016-01-01  2016-01-01     10
2016-01-04  2016-01-04      9
2016-02-05  2016-02-05      4
```

Comment: Wow, you're awesome. Thank you! I had to make one change because my array dtype was not `bool` but `int64` so I added `df.loc[df.resample('1M')['price'].transform(in_qrange, q=[0.1, 0.75]).astype(bool)]` and it worked like a charm!